# It's possible Solr 8 to upgrade to solr 9?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4, solrnet

It's possible  Solr 8 to upgrade to solr 9? Or does the old version feature I can add in Solr 9 version?

directly installation solr 9  some feature i needed from solr 8 are Deprecations and remove. [link](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/upgrade-notes/major-changes-in-solr-9.html#deprecations-and-removals)

Feature i need in solr 9  from solr 8

> /browse
> /velocity

Comment: Both `/browse` and `/velocity` should be present in Solr 8. But upgrade to Solr 9 - there are plenty of other reasons for doing that, such as the older versions of Solr 8 having vulnerable log4j jars by default.

Comment: Should I manually add this feature in Solr 9 ?

Comment: You must enable the feature yourself, regardless of which (recent) version you're using. Velocity (and thus `/browse`as well) as been removed from the core of 9.0, so in that case you'll have to add the external dependency as well. I was unable to locate where the community project currently lives.

Comment: I also tried to find a community project, but I failed. If you have any ideas, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/erikhatcher/solr-velocity ? I'm guessing this is where it's at now. Generally I'm guessing you might be better served by writing something yourself or trying to find a general Solr frontend instead of one bundled inside Solr.

Comment: yes, I check it and try to run the example, but facing a java error. 
{HTTP ERROR 500 {msg=access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader"), trace=java.security.AccessControlException: access denied }